# Awesome WM shortcut to kill window

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, awesome-wm

How can I set a shortcut to kill current window in awesome WM ?

I know <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> close a window, but what I want is KILL (`kill <PID>` for instance).

I need this to kill process a frozen window for example.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is killing the process that created a window. You can't do this out-of-the-box but might be able to do it under certain circumstances.

Please take a look at [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1131539) about why it is not usualy possible.

If you want to give it a try anyway, you'll have to get active window id in lua, try to retreive a PID from it and invoke a `kill -9` command on it. This is easily done use a tool like `xprop`, or you can use a command like this one (untested, probably not even working):

```
awful.key({ modkey, "Control"   }, "c",
    function (c) awful.util.spawn("kill -9 " .. get_xproperty("_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL)"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`client` class has `pid` property (at least in awesome 4.2 https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/client.html) so you can simply do this:

```
awful.key({ modkey, "Control"   }, "c",
    function (c)
        if c.pid then
            awful.spawn("kill -9 " .. c.pid)
        end
    end
)
```